# Activity Function needs current Time - Azure Functions

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

So I have a Durable Function that looks something like this:

```
    [FunctionName("functionName")]
    public async Task functionName([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
    {
       // some code here
       string name = "name";
       await context.CallActivityAsync("activityFunction", name);
    }

    [FunctionName("activityFunction")]
    public async Task ActivityFunction([ActivityTrigger] IDurableActivityContext name)
    {
        // perform an operation here
        // need to get current UTC time here
    }
```

There is no way to get the current UTC time from the activity context. How am I supposed to get it?

Comment: You need to use`DateTime.UtcNow`

Comment: Azure functions need to be deterministic, am unable to do that.

Comment: That's means you can not write code to get current date? Sorry I know little to nothing about azure functions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An activity function is at liberty to use `DateTime.UtcNow` or `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow` - the orchestrator will only run it once and then remember the result for subsequent replays. Orchestrator functions have to use the deterministic `IDurableOrchestrationContext.CurrentUtcDateTime` because it's important that code within the orchestrator itself returns the same value for every replay.

Comment: How about getting the UtcNow in Trigger function and then pass it as a parameter to Orchestrator and then to the Activity? We need to process some data for a specific datetime range [..., now], and I'm afraid there could be some offset between the Trigger function is raised and the Activity function is ran.